# Separate plots in different ones

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, data-visualization

How can I separate this line plot into two, one evaluating one variable (for 3 datasets) and the other graph for the other variable. It is more clear in the picture attached.

****EDIT****

```
def dfsubsets():

x = np.arange(1,ncol)

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[2, 1])
#GRAPH 1
ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
line0,=ax0.plot(x,models_best["Accuracy"],'-o',color='red',label='Best subset')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.title('best subset')
plt.ylim(bottom=0.46,top=0.79)



def backward_logistic():
#GRAPH 2
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1], sharex = ax0)
line1,=ax1.plot(x,models_best['MSE'],color='red')
plt.setp(ax0.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
yticks = ax1.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
yticks[-1].label1.set_visible(False)
plt.xlabel('Tamaño del subconjunto $k$')
plt.ylabel('MSE')
plt.legend()
```

It generates multiple subplots because I pass the functions in a new df:

```
 df_comparation=pd.DataFrame({
'modelo':['Best_subset','backward','forward'],
'Accuracy':[dfsubsets(),backward_logistic()]})
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest you read the [matplotlib subplot tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-subplots-demo-py) first. You will probably be able to find an answer to your question from these examples using `sharex`.

Comment: I can't find anything related with my problem in these tutorials...

Comment: You plot the same graph into two sharex subplots and set two different ylims for the subplots.

Comment: I edited my question. I used sharex and it kinda solved my problem, but I still need to plot the blue lines together and the red ones too in different graphs, as in the picture above, not in different grid plots. My purpose is to join 'MSE' graphs and 'Accuracy' graphs in order to see the differences among the models.

Comment: Why would this code above generate four subplots? It creates two subplots, and everything you want in the upper graph, you plot with `ax0.plot`, and everything for the lower subplot, you plot with `ax1.plot`

Comment: it generates multiple subplots because I pass the functions to a new df as stated above